# TDD, Ruby, & handling nil arguments

Tags: ruby, tdd

Part of the practice of TDD involves easing into the core functionality from the edges, and starting by testing the simplest, degenerate case. I'm working in Ruby, so I very often find myself writing a test like this:

```
it "does the thing if given nil" do
  expect { my_method(nil) }.to do_the_thing
end
```

and production code like this:

```
def my_method(arg)
  if arg.nil?
    do_the_thing
    return
  end

  do_the_real_thing
end
```

I don't like the idea of littering every public method with such guard-clauses, but given the dynamic nature of Ruby, where do you draw the line? When is it reasonable to put the responsibility for passing valid arguments on the calling code?

I'd like to write focused, expressive methods that aren't littered with overly-defensive code, but I also want to build a robust and correct system.

The practice of easing in from the edge-cases appeals to me, but I'm often unsure how this particular edge-case should be handled.

Comment: @sawa My question is about an aspect of the design that the tests are driving.

Comment: Can you use default values for parameter?  That may help to avoid `nil` getting passed to method

Comment: If you have many similar defensive code snippets, maybe you have missed the **refactor** part of TDD.

Comment: @WandMaker A default parameter value would come into play if the caller omitted the argument entirely, but I'm thinking about the case where a nil is passed explicitly, in which case the default would be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the decision on how defensive to write your code depends on how *reasonable* the circumstances of the error condition are.

The question you ask yourself is how reasonable is it to assume that this condition will occur in the normal course of events.

If in the normal course of events it is reasonable that an error may occur then it makes sense to code accordingly.

If in the normal course of events the error condition *should not* happen, then I would not put in a check condition. If the error condition occurs it is better to have the application throws a fatal error and stop working as there is something fundamentally wrong.

As an example, say you have a method that is accepting as a parameter a country name selected from a pre-defined list in a form. It is reasonable for the method to assume that it will get a valid country name. There is no reason for the method to do sanity checking on this (such as checking for a string that is not a valid country name).

In another example, say you have a method that is dealing with parameters from a database source that is known to be of poor data quality. In this situation it is reasonable to check to ensure that the parameters are what the method expects.

Writing code that is overly defensive may actually result in the hiding of some issues. I have seen code written that checks for completely unreasonable things, logs the issue and then carries on running. These applications typically have unpredictable behaviour as they are concealing coding problems that really should be dealt with.